# The API returns a 403 ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT eventhough I have the scopes enabled

Tags: google-apps-activity

I'm making a script which loads all the drive activity between two dates and puts them into an excel sheet. When trying to get the data it gives me the following response:

`{ "error": { "code": 403, "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.", "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", "details": [ { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo", "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT", "domain": "googleapis.com", "metadata": { "service": "driveactivity.googleapis.com", "method": "google.apps.drive.activity.v2.DriveActivityService.QueryDriveActivity" } } ] } }`

I can't figure out why it gives this error response, I have the scopes mentioned in the documentation enabled.

[image]

What i've tried:

I post to the following address:

https://driveactivity.googleapis.com/v2/activity:query?alt=json

I use a bearer token generated from my id an credentials.

I have tried reenabling the scopes and even enabling all scopes just incase but that did not seem to work.

EDIT:

The code is a small script for loading the drive activity into an excel sheet the language is VBA

part of the code:

```
api_url = "https://driveactivity.googleapis.com/v2/activity:query?alt=json"    
Dim d                   'Create a variable
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    d.Add "filter", "time > " & fromDate & " AND time <= " & toDate
    
    bearerToken = "[MYTOKEN]"
    postFilter = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(d)
    i = 2
    Do While Not (IsNull(api_url))
        Debug.Print (api_url)
        req.Open "POST", api_url
        req.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & bearerToken
        req.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        req.send postFilter
        Set Parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(req.responseText)
        Debug.Print (Parsed("next"))
        Set Results = Parsed("activities")
```

Comment: Could you please provide a sample code? It seems that you have the correct scopes in your project, however they might have not been called correctly over your code, what language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the error,

The issue was that while getting my access token (not bearer token) I used the drive api scope instead of the drive activity api scope.